# MySql CREATE TRIGGER INSERT also gets MAX PK id just inserted?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am coding my first `CREATE TRIGGER` in a MySQL table named `Item`.

I want to INSERT a new row INTO table `itemindustrycodeslookup` and get the Max `itemindustrycodeslookupId` value back in order to INSERT that value into the `Item` table.

Here is what I have so far:

```
-- Trigger DDL Statements
DELIMITER $$

USE `nextcart`$$

CREATE TRIGGER `insert_itemindustrycodeslookupid` 
    BEFORE INSERT ON `item` FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO `itemindustrycodeslookup` SET `itemindustrycodeslookupId` = NULL;
                    #SELECT here..
                    #INSERT here...
    END$$
```

Will I need a SELECT after that INSERT followed by another INSERT?

Also, I am not sure about `INSERT INTO`itemindustrycodeslookup`SET`itemindustrycodeslookupId`= NULL;` .. all columns can be null except the PK id which is auto-increment, and that is why I am saying to `SET`itemindustrycodeslookupId`= NULL`

**CODE UPDATE: I am still unsure if my delimiters are correct and I am not ready to hit the Apply button yet, but it is coming along.

```
-- Trigger DDL Statements
DELIMITER $$

USE `nextcart`$$

CREATE TRIGGER `insert_itemindustrycodeslookupid` 
    AFTER INSERT ON `item` FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE fk_id int;
        Set fk_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
        INSERT INTO `itemindustrycodeslookup` SET `itemindustrycodeslookupId` = NULL;
        UPDATE `item` SET `item`.`itemindustrycodeslookupId` = LAST_INSERT_ID() WHERE `item`.`itemId` = fk_id;
    END$$
```

***LATEST CODE UPDATE: This does work, scraped together from the web.. poster said to "use at own risk" so hope there is a better solution. MySQL DOES not like to update it's own table if it fired the Trigger so... anyway here is what DID work.

```
-- Trigger DDL Statements
DELIMITER $$

USE `nextcart`$$

CREATE
DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
TRIGGER `nextcart`.`insert_itemindustrycodeslookupid`
BEFORE INSERT ON `nextcart`.`item`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO nextcart.itemindustrycodeslookup SET itemindustrycodeslookupId = NULL;
    SET NEW.itemindustrycodeslookupId = (
        SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT - 1 
        FROM information_schema.TABLES 
        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE() 
        AND TABLE_NAME = 'itemindustrycodeslookup'
      );
END$$
```

***SOLUTION: Found this also works which may be your answer below..

```
-- Trigger DDL Statements
DELIMITER $$

USE `nextcart`$$

CREATE
DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
TRIGGER `nextcart`.`insert_itemindustrycodeslookupid`
BEFORE INSERT ON `nextcart`.`item`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO nextcart.itemindustrycodeslookup SET itemindustrycodeslookupId = NULL;
    SET NEW.itemindustrycodeslookupId = (
        SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID());
END$$
```

Comment: Can't UPDATE same table that fires Trigger? "Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'item' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function after an insert to get the new value of the auto increment id column for the row just inserted. ie:

```
 INSERT INTO `itemindustrycodeslookup` values (...);
 -- no need for a select
 INSERT INTO some_child_of_itemindustrycodeslookup values (..., LAST_INSERT_ID(), ...)
```

If you need to use it again, declare a variable to store it for reuse, as it will change when the child is inserted:

```
DECLARE last_id int;

INSERT INTO parent ...
SET last_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO child .. -- #1
INSERT INTO child .. -- #2
```

If the trigger is defined on the table being inserted into you would need to define the trigger to fire after insert.

Comment: Something like - INSERT INTO `nextcart`.`item` (`itemId`, `itemName`, `itemSku`, `itemPrice`, `itemIndustryCodesLookupId`, `isEnabled`) VALUES (NULL, 'Max Extract All-Terrain Carpet Washer', 'F7452900', NULL, LAST_INSERT_ID(), NULL); ??

Comment: Yes! Although I would leave out itemid and the null for it - mysql will create an id for it if you omit it from the insert statement.

Comment: Hi, I thought we had something, but I am seeing information on the web, StackOverflow.com etc that MySQL cannot UPDATE a table that fires a Trigger. Not sure what to do now.. I have updated my question with what we have so far.

Comment: You can change the data about to be inserted by setting values of the `NEW` row, eg `SET NEW.COLUMN_NAME = something;`

Comment: Thanks for your help. The solution that is working is actually a BEFORE INSERT Trigger